# JavaScript - remove space after a specific char

Tags: javascript, string, replace, char, space

I've found many solutions in JavaScript to remove all spaces in a string with `\s`. But I can't found a solution for my specific problem. I want to transform "2* 2 +3* 5" in "2*2+3*5" (no more space after '*'), I've tried with

```
mot = mot.replace(/*\s/g, '*');
```

But it doesn't work, does anyone have the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `*` character.

Try this: `"2* 2 +3* 5".replace(/\*\s/g,'*')`

Answer (score 0):

```
mot = mot.replace(/(\*)\s/g, "$1");
```

Note that you have to use `\` before a `*` because `*` is a reserved character. With this, you can also add more characters with no whitespace allowed after, like `*` and `+` here:

```
mot = mot.replace(/([*+])\s/g, "$1");
```

Now that the `*` is in a `[]` you don't need to esacpe it. And lastly, to remove multiple whitespaces at once, use

```
mot = mot.replace(/([*+])\s+/g, "$1");
```